# How do I get a list of admin users via GoCD API?

Tags: go-cd

How can I get a list of admin users via the GoCD API?
I thought it would be a role, but it's not.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I opened the config xml file and grabbed them from there :(

Answer (score 0):

Can't try, as don't have GoCD running around, but probably you can get configuration from [API](https://api.gocd.org/current/#get-configuration) and find out admin users from it?

From documentation:

> Returns: The contents of the configuration file.

And after that apply some xpath query.
Alternatively you can use my library [yagocd](https://github.com/grundic/yagocd) and get configuration xml from it (but you still have to play with XML yourself).

Oh, found sample [cruise-config.xml](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gocd/gocd/master/server/config/cruise-config.xml) in GoCD repo and here is xpath for you: `//admins/user/text()`.